# Hystrix Fallback Disable

Tags: annotations, command, hystrix, fallback

I am having a method which has hystrix annotation as follows:

eg:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="testMessage")

public boolean receiveMessage(String message, String destination) 

{


Code goes here



}
```

.

So I have a flag which when true the fallback should enable otherwise if false I need to disable the fallback. Is there anyway to do this.
Note we are using annotation,So is there a way to enable and disable the annotation means enable or disable the fallback based on the flag.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of Options I can think of.

1. Keep a static boolean variable. And change this based on your requirement. And in your fallback method, you can check for this variable and proceed further only of its not set. (Not so Clean)
2. (Better Solution )There is a Hystrix property `hystrix.command.default.fallback.enabled` which will let you disable the fallback as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#fallback.enabled)

You can set this at runtime ba getting hold of `ConfigurationManager` (com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager). Something like this

```
com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty("hystrix.command.default.fallback.enabled", false)// If you want to turn it off
```

Comment: Is there any other way to set this property hystrix.command.default.fallback.enabled.

Comment: you can always use annotations @HystrixProperty(name = HystrixPropertyManager.FALLBACK_ENABLED, value = "false") if you don't like the options provided above (I know too late response but I figured it's worth it for anyone interested)